# Magento : How to Get Related Attributes of a Collection

Tags: magento-1.9, product

My question is pretty simple. I have a collection like below.

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$collection->addAttributeToSelect(array('sku','name','price','thumbnail'));
$collection->setStoreId(1)->addCategoryFilter($categoryObj);
```

So above code returns all the products from a particular category.

I need to get all the attributes related to this collection, like layered navigation. Our way of generating layered navigation.

My output will be

Array 1 - All the products in the collection

Array 2 - Product related attributes values like below sample

```
Brands
Nike
Addidas
Under Armour
__________
Gender
Male
Female
Unisex
_________
Age Group
5-10 Years
10-15 Years
Big kids
```

Please advise

Comment: can you try Use Flat Catalog Category and Use Flat Catalog Product > yes after reindex and check

Answer (score 0):

You need to try this code.

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$collection->setStoreId(1)->addCategoryFilter($categoryObj);
```